# Max cursor issue

Tags: java, sql, oracle

We are having an issue with code.  The error I am getting a is maximum cursor open from oracle database in the java code.  Something we have tried Try-catch-finally, in the finally section close the resultSet and preparedStatement. Once all records are processed close the connection.

```
Map<String,String> idMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    try{

    Long aId = null;
    if(bId != null){

        aId = bId.toLong();
    }
    // Create the prepared statement
    retrieveStatement = super.prepareStatement( getSqlFromProps("findPersonInfo")  );
for(int i =0 ; i < 100; i++){
    super.setDate( 1, today, retrieveStatement ); 
    super.setDate( 2, today, retrieveStatement ); 
    super.setDate( 3, today, retrieveStatement ); 
    super.setDate( 4, today, retrieveStatement ); 
    super.setString( 5, theCaseNumber, retrieveStatement );
    super.setString( 6, theCaseId, retrieveStatement );
    super.setLong( 7, aId, retrieveStatement );
    super.executeUnboundedQuery(retrieveStatement); 

   }
    }catch(Exception e){
    }finally{
    if (retrieveStatement != null) {
            retrieveStatement.close();
        }
    }



    return idMap;
```

Comment: Please paste your code block.

Comment: That error almost always indicates that you've got a cursor leak in your application.  We'd need to see code to help you pinpoint the issue.

Comment: Missing `resultSet.close()` ?

Comment: It is impossible to give a definitive answer without seeing the code for the `super` class. If you're on Java 7/8, using [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for resource access in that class will likely fix your problem. Also, why are you not using the JDBC classes directly, but instead wrapping them within the superclass? This might prevent the JDBC resources from being garbage-collected.

Comment: Could you please post the super class?

Comment: Hello guys, Sorry I have been oof and out of the country due to personal reasons since may.  However we figured out the issue.  We need to close the resultset.  There was one method that was not closing them correct.

Answer (score 0):

Cursor is associated with resultset. Close resultset and cursor will be closed too and you will have no such exception.